# Using CLANG without install Visual Studio

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to build on Windows using CMake/Ninja and CLANG.  It still require me to install Visual Studio... Is there a way to compile on C++ code on Windows without installing Visual Studio?

I switched to Ninja build instead of MSBUILD but visual studio is still required

Comment: The question lacks of debugging info. Have you tuned a cmake toolchain for using clang?

Comment: Yes I have been using CMake and Ninja using Linux.  I have code that doesn't rely on any Windows features but I need to run on Windows.  I am just looking to build the same on Windows with with clang. What debugging information can I provide?  I can try to uninstall vs and try again. Thanks

Comment: If yes, then please show your toolchain file. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you. Yes it does. It says that CLANG needs either Visual Studio or MINGW.  I guess Visual Studio code is required in my case.

Comment: @273K Got it. Will keep that in mind for my future questions. Thank you.

Comment: Use "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022" to not have to install visual studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022

Comment: @Artyer Wow I was not aware of a download just for build tools.  Thank you so much.